# Colour the helper grid line in d3

Tags: typescript, d3.js

I draw a line chart and want helper grid lines.
I have problem with colouring them.

My code sets the colour 'red', but is applied to the tick format instead of the line.

[image]

```
...
this.mainContainer.append('g')
  .attr('stroke', 'red')
  .attr('stroke-width', 10)
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .call(this.make_y_gridlines()
    .tickSize(-xWidth)
  )
...

private make_y_gridlines() : Axis<number | { valueOf(): number; }> {        
  return d3.axisLeft(this.yScale)
      .ticks(10);
}
```